# access array(Ndarray) without space

Tags: python, arrays, numpy-ndarray, serpent

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkWzw.png)I have ndarray image=[0 0 0 0 0 4 4 4 0 4 4 4 0 1 4 1]
I would to encrypt it using serpent algorithm , so I need to take the ndarray(image) as input to the serpent , how i can do it

Note : I would to read ndarray value like this 0000044404440141 ( without space between item )

any one can help me , in python

Answer (score 1):

your can try this if your array is only one dimension:

```
"".join(str(num) for num in ndarray)
```

If your array is a nd-array (n>1) of numpy, then you maybe need to flatten it first:

```
"".join(str(num) for num in ndarray.ravel())
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about python but the approach for the same in java can be like using a StringBuilder object and concatenate each integers of the array to the StringBuilder object. like

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int value: array){
  sb.append(value);
}
String param= sb.toString();//if you want it to have as String
```

Now you can pass param as a string to the method needed.

Comment: many thanks ,but dtype of ndarray int8 , is that not important